# How can I select and delete parts of a single 3d layer in Adobe Photoshop CC 2015?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I imported an obj. file to Adobe Photoshop CC 2015 and the whole 3d model came as a single layer. It is a 3d racing suit model and I want to delete arms of the suit. I know I could use the quick selection tool and make a new layer from arm parts but since it is a 3d model, this method doesn't work on 3d meshes. I also tried the cross-section method but it too didn't work. I searched everywhere but couldn't find a proper method. Is there a way to select a part of a single 3d mesh, make a new layer out of it and delete it or simply erase a part of a single 3d layer?

Comment: Hi Starior, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: As far as I'm aware Photoshop can not alter .obj files. It can only rotate/texture them. To edit the .obj file you need a 3D construction app.

Comment: @Scott Oh... Can you suggest an application that has a tool to select and erase parts of a single entity?

Answer (score 1):

According to Adobe, it's not possible.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/essential-3d-concepts-tools-photoshop.html

> To edit the polygon mesh of the 3D model itself, you must use a 3D
>   authoring program.

So your best option would be to use a 3D software to do the job. Cinema4D, Blender, Sketchup, 3dMax and Maya have free versions and should be enough for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Layer mask works just fine to remove part of a layer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a free 3D Program like Blender or similar to edit the .obj and just delete the Polygons of the Arm.

[Blender Dowload](https://www.blender.org/)